Error: app must have required property 'runtime' in Forge CLI during deploy
I'm facing an issue while trying to deploy my Forge app. When I run the forge deploy command, I encounter the following error:
D:\CodeGist-2024\Instant-Resolver-App> forge deploy
D:\CodeGist-2024\Instant-Resolver-App\manifest.yml 21:0    error    app must have required property 'runtime'  valid-document-required
Error: Command failed due to validation error.
Expected Behavior: I expected the forge deploy command to successfully deploy my app.
Actual Behavior: The deployment fails with the error indicating that the runtime property is missing, even though I have included it in my manifest.yml file.
What I Have Tried and Research Conducted:
1. Verified the runtime Property: Ensured it's correctly specified in manifest.yml.
2. Checked for Syntax Errors: Reviewed for any syntax issues or incorrect indentation.
3. Ensured Correct Path: Confirmed paths in manifest.yml are accurate.
4. Updated Forge CLI: Using the latest version of Forge CLI.
5. Referenced Documentation: Reviewed Forge documentation for required format.
6. Searched for Similar Issues: Looked through forums and Stack Overflow but found no solution.
7.Tested with Minimal Configuration: Simplified manifest.yml
Here is the content of my manifest.yml file:
modules:
  webtrigger:
    - key: instant-resolver-webtrigger
      handler: backend/aggregation.run
  function:
    - key: instant-resolver-function
      handler: backend/ai.run
  trigger:
    - key: instant-resolver-trigger
      function: instant-resolver-function
      events:
        - avi:jira:issue_created
  frontend:
    - key: instant-resolver-frontend
      resource: main
      path: frontend/build
      resolver:
        function: backend/api/index.run
        method: get

app:
  id: ari:cloud:ecosystem::app/521a1fb1-477b-49aa-***********

runtime:
  name: nodejs18.x


try putting runtime inside app
